# Preencher automaticamente campo em uma página web a qual não posso alterar

Tags: javascript, html5

**Bom dia amigos!**
Estou começando a me aventurar no mundo da programação, e me deparei com uma duvida.
É possivel preencher automaticamente os campos de uma página web a qual não posso alterar o código?
Se sim poderiam me indicar oque devo estudar?

Desde já obrigado!!

Comment: Veja o tampermonkey para implementar user scripts, ou seja, scripts que vc altera do lado do usuário apenas